# $A^2 = 0$ and a square matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a square matrix, and $A^2 = 0$.

Prove that for every a, the matrix $I+aA$ is invertible.

Well, $(I + aA)(I -aA) = I$

and $I - (aA)^2 = I$ and from here $(aA)^2 = 0$, and from here $A^2 = 0$, but I think I'm missing something. can anyone correct me to prove that for every $a$ it will be true.

Comment: What's the problem? You found the inverse for $I+aA$.

Comment: Yea, just solved it. thx.

Answer (score 5):

It's ok, because you have $(I + aA)(I -aA) = (I-aA)(I+aA)= I$, so $I-aA$ is inverse for $I+aA$ by [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it a bit differently (this is an overkill)

- If $a=0$, you're done.
- If $a\neq 0$, you want to prove that $\det(I+aA)\neq 0$

But  $\det(I+aA)=\chi_A(-a)$

Since $A^2=0$, $\chi_A=X^n$

Therefore,  $\det(I+aA)=\chi_A(-a)\neq 0$